# fair semaphore in java

Tags: java, semaphore

I'm writing a program which mostly operates concurrent operations and access some objects that should not be accessed concurrently.

I first tries to lock a reentrentLock on a specific object but then I found it causes starvation and some threads just can't get that lock.
Then I thought about using semaphore which will give permits by the order of asking.

So, Is there any implementation for a fair semaphore in java?

Comment: maybe `java.util.concurrent.Semaphore(int permits, boolean fair)`

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger, Ok. this is clearly a sign for me to go to sleep and start again tomorrow. thanks anyway mate!

Answer (score 0):

The `Semaphore` class offers a constructor which accepts a boolean flag which can be used to enable fairness: [public Semaphore(int permits, boolean fair)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html#Semaphore(int,%20boolean))